# Inverted Axis in AXLSX Bar Chart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, excel, axlsx

I'm using this very straightforward code (practically the same as the bar chart examples [here](https://github.com/randym/axlsx/blob/master/examples/example.rb), however I am noticing that the Axes are inverted. The data that should be on the Val axis is shown on the Cat axis.

This is also true for the example linked above, and I can't seem to find a way to put them in the correct order.

Below is an image of the problem. The code used to generate it is:

```
sheet.add_chart(Axlsx::Bar3DChart,:title => "Chart", :show_legend => false, :start_at => "A1", :end_at => "P30", :bar_dir => :col) do |chart|
   chart.add_series :data => sheet["B1:B25"], :labels => sheet["A1:A25"]
   chart.valAxis.gridlines = false
   chart.catAxis.gridlines = false
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it. You can find my fork of axlsx here: https://github.com/HansCz/axlsx.

A pull request will be sent to https://github.com/randym/axlsx

Comment: That is absolutely amazing. Do you mind discussing what the issue was?

Comment: Excel files are basically XML files in a zip file. In the xml that defines a bar graph, the order in which axes are attached to the data is significant. This order was simply the wrong way round :)

Comment: Incidentally, another guy made the same fix as me, but better structured. It's up as a pull request on the original axlsx repo including comments here: https://github.com/randym/axlsx/pull/203

Comment: I've had a look at it, thank you so much for working this one out !